# Scope of a variable holding a jQuery object (via selector) not global

Tags: jquery, global-variables

Can anyone tell me why the scope of $mytextarea, in the code below, doesn't extend into the getAnswerToo() function?

getAnswer() works because I'm explicitly selecting the element I want updated. However, trying to use a global 'handler' variable doesn't work.

I'm assuming that this problem with the scope of the variable is specifically related to the fact that it holds a jQuery object. The other variable, myurl, works fine.

Any help much appreciated!

```
var myurl = "php/getAnswer.php";

var $mytextarea = null;  //  a handler for the textarea element
$mytextarea = $('textarea#mytextarea');

getAnswerToo();

    function getAnswer(){ // works

        var request = $.ajax({
          url: myurl,
          type: "POST",
          data: {question: questionId, user: userId},
          dataType: "html",
          success: function(data) {
            $('textarea#mytextarea').val(unescape(data));
          }
        });

    }

    function getAnswerToo(){ // doesn't work

        var request = $.ajax({
          url: myurl,
          type: "POST",
          data: {question: questionId, user: userId},
          dataType: "html",
          success: function(data) {
            $mytextarea.val(unescape(data));
          }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Thank you to both Aktee and Amareswar - of course! It's makes complete sense when you remember that jQuery selectors can only reference an object after the DOM has initialized. I'd stupidly put my code outside of the document ready function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is this placed?

```
$mytextarea = $('textarea#mytextarea');
```

Selector works when your DOM is initialized. 
This should work:

```
$(function() {     
   $mytextarea = $('textarea#mytextarea'); 
   getAnswerToo();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('textarea#mytextarea')` returns empty array as the DOM is not initialized yet. Wrap entire code with in code block while will be invoked after DOM is ready.